# how to send data from a dynamic route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an item and when I click on more info button a modal window with description appears but there is no endpoint like /modal in current route cause it's not external page I redirect to.
So in my modal window I have make a bid button and I can set a price in case I'm logged in.
otherwise Modal window with login form should appear with a request to log in.

This modal is on my navBar that is fixed whether I'm on current page or another one.
So how to pass this Modal Log in  using function  from another component ?

Here is my Modal with item description:

```
const ModalDetails = (props) => {
   console.log(props, ' for modal')
   const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn]  = useState(false)

   const checkUser = () => {
        if (!loggedIn) {
            /// how to pass that path to log in modal??
        }
    }

return (
{ item.typeSale == 'auction' && <button className='btn-item auction-btn-bet' 
       onClick={checkUser}>Make a bet</button>}

)
    }
```

Log in modal in my App.js

```
const App = () => {
...
  <Nav.Link className=' nav-item link-nav button-nav'  onClick={handleShow}>
                             <img className='img-small' src={person} />
                            Log in
                            
  </Nav.Link>

    <LoginForm show={show} handleShow={handleShow} handleClose={handleClose} />  

}
```

I have everything as a separate component

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. I think you can use Redux or Context to store the modal's open state.